# How do I make a Google account my default when I can't sign out of other accounts?

Tags: google-account, account-management, account-recovery

My school blocked the thing where we can switch our accounts (although I found a way to sign in to my other accounts) and I hate having to change my account every time I want to do something. How do I make one of these a default when I can't sign out of my other accounts?

Comment: You can open Incognito window in your browser, then login to your Google account, it will be your default while you using that Incognito window.

Comment: Does this happens on any browser? Have you tried on Firefox?

Comment: yeah it's on every browser :P